# SQL query to find due date for different withdraw

Tags: sql

I have a table like below -

[image]

Please help to write a SQL query to find worst due_date_passed in all transaction happened to a particular account_id. Because latest withdraw amount is showing only 30 days passed days however I need to marked account is due for past 120 days not 30 days.
Pls let me know th SQL query for the same.
Thanks

Comment: Dont use an image for your code. You will receive less help.

Comment: Show us some more sample table data and also _specify_ the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links.) Also show us your current query attempt. And add a tag for the dbms used - when it comes to date/time many products have their own functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    account_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN due_date_passed > 120 THEN due_date_passed ELSE 120 END) AS worst_due_date_passed
FROM 
    your_table_name
WHERE 
    account_id = <your_account_id>
GROUP BY 
    account_id;
```

Replace your_table_name with the actual name of your table, and <your_account_id> with the specific account ID you're interested in.

Comment: Hi @David - Max value could be anything, it might  be more than 120 days. I need find max

Answer (score 0):

Your question asked for the worst `due_date_passed`, which is straight forward: -

```
SELECT
    account_id,
    MAX(due_date_passed) max_due_date_passed
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    account_id
```

However, the question title asks for the due date, in which case you can use a sub-query: -

```
SELECT *
FROM
    table_name t1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        account_id,
        MAX(due_date_passed) max_due_date_passed
    FROM
        table_name
    GROUP BY
        account_id
    ) t2
ON
    t1.account_id = t2.account_id AND t1.due_date_passed = t2.max_due_date_passed
```